# Server and client checking in with one another

Tags: java, client-server, apache-mina

I would like to set up an Apache Mina process where clients and servers communicate using a callback mechanism that the server could call when it detects when a new file has appeared along with a simple function that lets me know whether all systems are up and running or not.

Any help would be much appreciated, I have created a simple TimeServer and TimeHandler program in netbeans which compiles and runs.